# What is the return type of View::make in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I like clean docs and phpdoc will automagically look up the type. When documenting a controller function that returns View::make, I have no idea what type to use for the @return in my documentation.

```
<?php

class FooController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Show a view.
     *
     * @return  ??? description of the view
     */
    public function show(){
        return View::make('bar');
    }

}
```

What is the type here or is there a better way to document the function for this purpose?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The return value is

```
Illuminate\View\View
```

I traced through the ServiceProvider which lead me to

```
Illuminate\View\Environment::make
```

Which is line 113 of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php (in 4.1 at least)

```
/**
 * Get a evaluated view contents for the given view.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  array   $data
 * @param  array   $mergeData
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function make($view, $data = array(), $mergeData = array())
{
    $path = $this->finder->find($view);

    $data = array_merge($mergeData, $this->parseData($data));

    $this->callCreator($view = new View($this, $this->getEngineFromPath($path), $view, $path, $data));

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good find, though your documentation is poor. You should document more than just type names.

Comment: Oops, that's not your code, is it? Laravel's [comment] documentation, then!

Comment: Yeah, that's core code, and this instance I think the comments suffice as this function will always return something slightly different, so this is the closest it can get it with any degree of accuracy.

Comment: I dunno.. some prose about the intended form of the input parameters wouldn't go amiss, _especially_ for core code.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this is covered in the documentation, which should also be the first port of call for finding out how something works. Especially considering most people wouldn't even know this file exists.

Comment: Opinion: It is unfortunate that there is so much poorly documented or undocumented code out there. One would think that publishers of "frameworks" that aspire to wider use would provide better docs. Fancy tutorials and overview documentation with use cases are nice to have. Real standardized documentation with human readable descriptions for parameters, returns and other function properties are essential rules of the road as far as I'm concerned. Then again, I have written my fair share of undocumented code.